Google Ads API Keyword Planner works on macOS but breaks on Ubuntu with "Specified API version 'v17' does not exist" error
I have been working with the Google Ads API to generate keyword ideas using the Keyword Planner. The script works perfectly fine on macOS, and I've tested it on multiple Mac machines without any issues. However, when I try to run the same script on an Ubuntu machine, it fails with the following error:
root@545d9b292810:/app# python3 generate_keyword_ideas.py --customer_id 473727
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/ads/googleads/client.py", line 203, in _get_api_services_by_version
    version_module = import_module(f"google.ads.googleads.{version}")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.ads.googleads.v17'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_keyword_ideas.py", line 176, in <module>
    main(
  File "generate_keyword_ideas.py", line 38, in main
    keyword_plan_idea_service = client.get_service("KeywordPlanIdeaService")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/ads/googleads/client.py", line 356, in get_service
    api_module = self._get_api_services_by_version(version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/ads/googleads/client.py", line 205, in _get_api_services_by_version
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Specified Google Ads API version "v17" does not exist. Valid API versions are: "v11", "v10", "v9"


What I've Tried:
I have confirmed that the Google Ads API library version 17.0.0 is installed on both macOS and Ubuntu.
The Python version on Ubuntu is 3.8, and I ensured that all dependencies are correctly installed.
I’ve tried reinstalling the google-ads package and even setting up a fresh virtual environment.
The script works flawlessly on macOS, so the issue seems to be specific to Ubuntu.
The script should run on Ubuntu just as it does on macOS without throwing the "Specified Google Ads API version 'v17' does not exist" error.
Specifications:
Python version: 3.8 on Ubuntu
Google Ads API library version: 17.0.0
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
